# If else function with identical symbols

Tags: go

I have this:

```
func main() {
  n1 := new(big.Int)
  n1.SetString("1000000", 10)

  n2 := new(big.Int)
  n2.SetString("1000009", 10)

  one := big.NewInt(1)

  for i := n1; i.Cmp(n2) < 0; i.Add(i, one) {
    //fmt.Println(i)
  }
}
```

How do I make when n1 := 100000 <-- got 5 identical symbols or 122222 and etc just to keep count till there is only 4 identical symbols (example 100001) ... then go to next line.

I know I need to use ... if ... else ... but I have no idea how to check if there is only 4 identical symbols in result of n1

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you mean or not, but I can suggest you create a function which accepts a `*big.Int` and a specific number of identical symbols, and returns weather or not there's a character that is repeated `n` times:

```golang
func containsNIdenticalSymbols(n int, i *big.Int) bool {
    counter := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, char := range i.String() {
        counter[char] ++
    }
    hasNumIdenticalSymbols := false
    for _, count := range counter {
        if count == n { hasNumIdenticalSymbols = true; break }
    }
    return hasNumIdenticalSymbols
}
```

And just `&&` it with the `i.Cmp(n2) < 0` condition:

```golang
numIdenticalSymbols := 4
//                            as you said "keep count till there is only 4 identical symbols"
for i := n1; i.Cmp(n2) < 0 && !containsNIdenticalSymbols(numIdenticalSymbols, i) ; i.Add(i, one) { ... }
```

Comment: And how can it be - all, except those that have 4 or more identical symbols?